# Can I show Web Page wtih Google Adsense in Chrome Custom Tabs?

Tags: android, adsense, chrome-custom-tabs

I read in some websites like, showing webpage which contains google adsense in Android webview is against their policy.

I would like to know, whether we can show the web page with google adsense in chrome custom tabs?

I have a news website and android app. I am showing short news in app and while clicking on the more button in app, it will open the web page in browser. I am not opening the web page in webview, as my web page contains google ads. Could anyone please suggest, whether I can open the webpage inside my app using chrome custom tabs functionality? Please share your idea and experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [support link](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en), you can show Adsense on Chrome Custom Tabs.

> **Format requirements** 
>  - WebView 
>   AdSense for content (AFC) and Ad Exchange (AdX) display ads are not supported through all WebView technologies. App developers wishing to monetize by publishing AFC and AdX display ads through a WebView must use one of the following supported viewing frames:
>    - Android: Chrome Custom Tab
>    - iOS: SFSafariViewController (iOS9 and iOS10 only)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use chrome custom tabs functionality

Use this code below :

```
dependencies {      
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.4.0'
}
```

**Open a Chrome custom tab** :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://segunfamisa.com");

// create an intent builder
CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();

// Begin customizing
// set toolbar colors
intentBuilder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
intentBuilder.setSecondaryToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

// set start and exit animations
intentBuilder.setStartAnimations(this, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
intentBuilder.setExitAnimations(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
        android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

// build custom tabs intent
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = intentBuilder.build();

// launch the url
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(activity, uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are worried about Ad placement policies.

> **Ads in a software application**
>
> *Publishers are not permitted to distribute Google ads or AdSense for search boxes through software applications including, but not limited
>   to toolbars, browser extensions, and desktop applications. AdSense
>   code may only be implemented on web-based pages and approved WebView
>   technologies.*

[Here](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/-4-f47U9QVc/Sup6oMFsBAAJ) is reply from Ads Support team for your concern.

> If you, yourself choose to open an ad in a new tab when you click it
>   yourself (on someone else's site), then that's a viewer choice and
>   nobody can stop you.
>
> If you mean you want to set the ads on your own website to open in a
>   new tab, then no, you cannot do that as it would violate ad placement
>   policies.

Hope it's clear now.